# how to capture JDBCConnectionException using Junit and Mockito?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, junit, mockito

I have a method which has the following code in it, it saves a order object to the orderStatus jpa repository and i have a try catch method which should capture the JDBC Connection exception.

How do i test this scenario using Junit and mockito?

```
try {
          orderStatusRepository.save(newOrderStatus);
      } catch (JDBCConnectionException ex) {
          
           
          );
```

Comment: Have a look at asserThrow API in junit

Answer (score 0):

If the code is the goal is to test that in case JDBCConnectionException is thrown it is caught and not propagated I would suggest to mock orderStatusRepository using Mockito:

```
when(orderStatusRepository.save(newOrderStatus))
    .thenThrow(JDBCConnectionException.class);
```

then execute the test and check that the method returns normally and that mocked object method was accessed (the exception therefor was thrown):

```
    verify(orderStatusRepository).save(newOrderStatus);
```

Note that if `save` method doesn't return anything you would need to mock it a bit differently:

```
doThrow(JDBCConnectionException.class)
    .when(orderStatusRepository).save(newOrderStatus);
```

Answer (score 0):

follow the below code to test your code for the JDBC connection exception.

```
@MockBean
private OrderStatusRepository orderStatusRepository;
@Test
public void jdbcConnectionExceptionTest() {
    try{
        when(orderStatusRepository.save(newOrderStatus))
                .thenThrow(JDBCConnectionException.class);
        orderStatusRepository.save(newOrderStatus);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        assertTrue(e instanceof JDBCConnectionException);
    }
}
```